# Determining function of Graph

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, multivalued-functions

Looking through some notes on numerical computation I came across the following graph:

[image]

I know this is a longshot, but I'm not incredibly mathsy and would like to know what kind of a function this is, or what other functions it consists of (trigonometric/exponential/...). And why it looks like a perfect step with a "dent" in the middle. I mean, other than that "dent", it looks like a perfect step.

I'm guessing that "dent" is something exponential or logarithmic?

I'm probably totally wrong, any ideas?

I'm guessing it was chosen for a reason, probably a popular function, so maybe someone knows exactly what function it is. If not, that's fine, it's not essential, just wondering.